# Get-Service from ArrayList against remote servers, returning wrong results?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How to get the specific services based on the exact specific service name listed on the array of strings on a remote server?

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  DFS                DFS Namespace                         
Running  DFSR               DFS Replication                       
Running  DNS                DNS Server                            
Running  EventSystem        COM+ Event System                     
Running  IsmServ            Intersite Messaging                   
Running  KDC                Kerberos Key Distribution Center      
Running  LANMANServer       Server                                
Running  LANMANWorkstation  Workstation                           
Running  Netlogon           NETLOGON                              
Running  NTDS               Active Directory Domain Services      
Running  RPCSs              Remote Procedure Call (RPC)           
Running  SAMSs              Security Accounts Manager             
Running  W32Time            Windows Time
```

Because the below script returns the wrong services from the supplied name from **$ServiceList** variable.

There was no mention about Afd service, but it still showing:

[image: There was no mention about Afd service, but it still showing?]

One of the required Services on the list, DNS is not even showing:

[image: One of the required Services on the list, DNS is not even showing?]

Note: the Powershell ISE has been executed as Administrator and has Domain Admins credentials. The script has been executed successfully with no issue, however, the results are not according to the specific lists of  $ServiceList variable content.

This is the script I have so far:

```
$ServiceList = @(
    'DFS'
    'DFSR'
    'DNS'
    'EventSystem'
    'IsmServ'
    'KDC'
    'LANMANServer'
    'LANMANWorkstation'
    'NETLOGON'
    'NTDS'
    'RPCSs'
    'SAMSs'
    'W32Time'
)

$input = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName
$input | ForEach-Object `
{
    $Servers = ($_ -split '\.')[0]
    
    $Servers | ForEach-Object `
    {
        $Server = $_
        
        Write-Host "Processing $($Server) ..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet)
        {
            foreach ($ServiceToCheck in $ServiceList)
            {
                Write-Host "`tChecking $($Server) - $($ServiceToCheck) ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
                
                Try
                {
                    If ($services = Get-Service -ServiceName $ServiceToCheck -ComputerName $Server)
                    {
                        $services | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServicesDependedOn | Select-Object StartType, Status, Name, DisplayName, Machinename, @{ N = 'Service Dependency'; E = { (Get-Service -Name $_.ServicesDependedOn -ComputerName $Server | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name): $($_.Status)" }) -join '; ' } }
                    }
                    Else
                    {
                        "" | Select-Object @{ n = "Status"; e = { "Services not found" } },
                                           @{ n = "DisplayName"; e = { "$($_.Services)" } },
                                           @{ n = "Machinename"; e = { $Server } }
                    }
                }
                Catch
                {
                    "" | Select-Object @{ n = "Status"; e = { "Error checking services" } },
                                       @{ n = "DisplayName"; e = { "" } },
                                       @{ n = "Machinename"; e = { $Server } }
                }
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            "" | Select-Object @{ n = "Status"; e = { "Couldn't ping server" } },
                               @{ n = "DisplayName"; e = { "" } },
                               @{ n = "Machinename"; e = { $Server } }
        }
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable, so you should not use that name as self-defined variable. Also, the second ForEach-Object loop is redundant, since you're already looping one domain controller at a time.

Comment: Hi @Theo thank you for the update. Changing the $input variable somehow not improving the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a rewrite of your code.

I have removed variable `$input`, as that is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell.

I also got rid of the second `$Servers | ForEach-Object` loop and made sure all parts of the code output a similar object to output in the GridView

```
$ServiceList = 'DFS','DFSR','DNS','EventSystem','IsmServ','KDC','LANMANServer',
               'LANMANWorkstation','NETLOGON','NTDS','RPCSs','SAMSs','W32Time'

Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName | ForEach-Object {
    $Server = ($_ -split '\.')[0]  # get the server name from the HostName
   
    Write-Host "Processing $($Server) ..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        foreach ($ServiceToCheck in $ServiceList) {
            Write-Host "`tChecking $($Server) - $($ServiceToCheck) ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            
            Try {
                $svc = Get-Service -ServiceName $ServiceToCheck -ComputerName $Server -ErrorAction Stop
                if ($svc) {
                    # successfully found a service
                    # get basic info about services this service depends on (if any)
                    $dependingOn = (Get-Service -Name $_.ServicesDependedOn -ComputerName $Server | 
                                    ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name): $($_.Status)" }) -join '; '
                    $svc | Select-Object StartType, Status, Name, DisplayName, Machinename, 
                                         @{ n = 'Service Dependency'; e = { $dependingOn } }
                }
                else {
                    # service not found
                    "" | Select-Object StartType, 
                                       @{ n = "Status"; e = { "Service not found" } },
                                       @{ n = "Name"; e = { $ServiceToCheck } },
                                       DisplayName,
                                       @{ n = "Machinename"; e = { $Server } },
                                       'Service Dependency'
                }
            }
            Catch {
                # Get-Service returned an error in $_.Exception.Message
                "" | Select-Object StartType,
                                   @{ n = "Status"; e = { "Error checking services" } },
                                   @{ n = "Name"; e = { $ServiceToCheck } },
                                   DisplayName,
                                   @{ n = "Machinename"; e = { $Server } },
                                   'Service Dependency'
            }
            
        }
    }
    else {
        # server is off-line
        "" | Select-Object StartType,
                           @{ n = "Status"; e = { "Couldn't ping server" } },
                           @{ n = "Name"; e = { $ServiceToCheck } },
                           DisplayName,
                           @{ n = "Machinename"; e = { $Server } },
                           'Service Dependency'
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

Please can you check this and let us know?

Comment: many thanks for the great assistance as always, it is working great, you've been very helpful to this community.